# Interface with default methods and fields

Tags: inheritance, events, java-11

I'm in java and I'd like to implement a event-sender as an interface, so I could still use inheritance.

My idea was to use default methods and a common field defined within the interface. But this does not compile (I can't add the field to the interface).

```
interface dispatcher{

public EventListenerList listeners = null;
default public void fireNetEvent(String desc, TYPE val, String newStatus){
                 
     Event event = new NetEvent(this, desc, EVENT.NOTIFY_WITH_USER_DEFINED_TYPE, newStatus, val);
                 Object[] listenersArray = listeners.getListenerList();
                 for(int i = listenersArray.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2){
                     if(listenersArray[i] == NetEventListener.class){
                     ((NetEventListener)listenersArray[i+1]).NetStatusChanged(event);
                    }
                 }
             }
    default public void addNetListener(NetEventListener listener){
                if(listeners = null)
                    listeners = new ListenerList();
        listeners.add(NetEventListener.class, listener);
    }

    default public void removeNetListener(NetEventListener listener){
        listeners.remove(NetEventListener.class, listener);
    }

}
```

What's the best option, given the classes the use these methods still use inheritance?

Comment: An interface field is always `public static final`. It’s impossible to add per-instance state with an interface. That’s the fundamental difference between classes and interface.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clearer.